# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] when converting Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I'm having a huge issue with some I code I've converted to Swift. When calling `self.tableView.endUpdates()` my table view stays empty and I get the following error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1501
```

Weirdly enough when the same code was written in Objective-C this error is not showing up.

The table view datasource and delegate ar still in Objective-C and used by many other view controllers in the project.

Here is the code in Objective-c:

```
self.dataSource.itemArray = [self.userList copy];
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSUInteger i = (offset); i < (end); i++) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[indexPaths copy]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

And this is the same code but then in swift:

```
self.dataSource.itemArray = self.userList.copy() as! [User]
var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
for i in offset...end {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
     indexPaths.append(indexPath)
}
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

The `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called correctly and return the same in both case. Also the cell are correctly registered.

Is there a know issue or is ia just that I can't extent an Objective-C base class in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
for i in offset...end {
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
   indexPaths.append(indexPath)
}
```

The last `indexPath` which will be added is `NSIndexPath(forRow: end, inSection: 0)`, that means that you are adding one extra row to your table view which is not expected.

Probably you want to change your loop to:

```
for i in offset..<end {
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
   indexPaths.append(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: More common way is to write: `for i in offset..<end`

Comment: That might be one issue, but when ussing a `NSFecthedResultsController` i'm still getting the same issue, even do though it is using the Objective-C class that work in Objective-C version.

Comment: @rckoenes Have you fixed the issue I was pointing to and still getting the same error?

Comment: @njuri yes this seem to work, but not for the `NSFecthedResultsController` classes. It was actually a really stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

> myTableView.reloadSections([sectionIndex], with: .none)

did work and removed the error. It may be due to any button or textfield tag getting wrong index after row deletion.